# Generating an array of random numbers using two functions

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random

I am trying to generate an array whose elements are random numbers in a range (between a min value and max value), but something goes wrong. Code right below.

```
void cria_aleatorio(int *vetor, int tamanho, int min, int max) {
    int i=0;

    for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++)
    {
        vetor[i] = (rand() % (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
}

void print_vetor(int *vetor, int tamanho){
    printf("%d", vetor[tamanho]);
    printf("%d", tamanho);
}
```

Comment: What goes wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? You have "two functions" but only one is about random numbers.

Comment: You fill vetor from 0 to tamanho-1, then ask for vetor[tamanho], which is past the end of the array.

Comment: That might not be the same `tamanho`, it might be called from a loop. we don't know.

Comment: The other function should just print the array and its size. The problem is that I got an overflow every time it runs

Comment: The other function does not print the array. You can't throw an array at the `%d` format specifier - it prints *one* value. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comments, your print_vetor function is wrong. You need a loop to iterate over each element in the array, just like you do when you generate the random numbers.

```
void print_vetor(int *vetor, int tamanho){
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
        printf("%d, ", vetor[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%d\n", tamanho);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I had ready!.

Comment: @WeatherVane great minds think alike!